# how to get a list's add new item URL with JSOM?

Tags: 2010, javascript, csom, jsom

I'm trying to figure out how I can get a list's add new item URL using **JSOM** in SharePoint 2010. This is what I have so far to get if the current user has edit access on the list.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
{
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Shared Documents");
    clientContext.load(list);
    clientContext.load(list, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function()
    {
        if(list.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems))
        {
            // has edit permissions
        }
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function(){}));
}, "sp.js");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load `DefaultNewFormUrl` property of the list. Example:

```
clientContext.load(list, 'DefaultNewFormUrl');
```

Then retrieve it in the success method:

```
var newUrl = list.get_defaultNewFormUrl();
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess your are looking for [SP.List.defaultNewFormUrl property (sp.js)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246292.aspx).

```
var value = SP.List.get_defaultNewFormUrl();
```

Try following

```
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Shared Documents");
var listNewForm = list.get_defaultNewFormUrl();
```

**PS:** *MSDN* documentation reads that

**Applies to:**

apps for SharePoint | SharePoint Foundation 2013 | SharePoint Server 2013

I think it should work in SharePoint 2010 also. Try and let me know.